# Retrieve wp_terms by category_name

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to limit the retrieved testimonial (using `get_terms`) by their category names.
category_name = "xxx" doesn't seem to do anything so I'm at a loss.

```
function testimonial_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $cat = $atts['cat'];

        $testim='<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">';    
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'testimonial',
            'category_name' => $cat,
            'hide_empty' => true,
            ) );
        foreach($terms as $custom_texonomy){
            $imageid=get_option("testimonial_".$custom_texonomy->term_id."_testimonials__image");

            $imgurl=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageid, 'full');

            $testim.=' <div class="item">
    ...

    }
    add_shortcode( 'testimonialcat', 'testimonial_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'category_name' isn't a valid argument for get_terms.
The [WP reference documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) 
 lists the acceptable arguments. The one you want is:

**'name'**: (string|array) Optional. Name or array of names to return term(s) for.

So, assuming $cat is the name you want to search for, try changing your get_terms arguments to:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'testimonial',
        'name' => $cat,
        'hide_empty' => true,
        ) );
```

**Update:**

`get_terms` only returns information about the *term* you searched for, as per your original question.

To get all *posts* associated with a term, you need to use `get_posts` and `tax_query` as follows:

```
    $myposts = get_posts(array(
        'showposts' => -1, // get all posts
        'post_type' => 'post', // change to whatever post type you want, or leave out if you want to get all post types
        'tax_query' => array( 
                          array( 
                            'taxonomy' => 'testimonial', 
                            'field' => 'name', 
                            'terms' => $cat
                         ))
    ));
```

Reference: [get_posts documentation in WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: This kind of works. Basically, what I'm seeing now is the first post from that category, then the loop stops. Any idea why that is?

Comment: If you only search for one name, then I would only expect 1 result. `get_terms` returns details of the term you searched for and I assume you only have 1 term with that name in your taxonomy. Were you trying to get the posts associated with that term?

Comment: Yeah...trying to loop through everything from the custom post type category...any suggestions?

Comment: @LukeBriedis, I've updated my answer to get all posts for that term name

Comment: I had to add this to get the termid for my custom field retrieval, as it was voiden when using get_posts ---

    $id = get_term_by( slug, $cat, 'testimonial' );
  $id = $id->term_id;

Comment: @LukeBriedis I'm not really sure what you mean or where you had to do that, but I assume everything is working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

category_name is not a valid arg for get_terms, try 'name' instead:

```
function testimonial_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $cat = $atts['cat'];

            $testim='<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">';    
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'testimonial',
            'name' => $cat,
            'hide_empty' => true,
            ) );
        foreach($terms as $custom_texonomy){
            $imageid=get_option("testimonial_".$custom_texonomy->term_id."_testimonials__image");

            $imgurl=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageid, 'full');

            $testim.=' <div class="item">
    ...

    }
    add_shortcode( 'testimonialcat', 'testimonial_shortcode' );
```